# R Plotly Deselect trace by default

Tags: r, plotly

I am ussing R Plotly and have a line of the form:

```
add_trace(y = meanRank,
          x = DateOnly,
          data = timeSeriesDF,
          name = "Daily Value",
          text = hoverText,
          hoverinfo = "text",
          showlegend = TRUE)
```

It works fine. However, I want this trace to be "unselected" when the plot is shown. So a user would click it on the legend to show the line. I can't seem to find the parameter to show that.

Comment: Please read [how to provide minimal reproducible examples in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example#answer-5963610). You may want to edit & improve your question (and future ones) accordingly. A good R-related post usually provides minimal input data, the desired output data & code tries - all copy-paste-run'able in a new/clean R session.

Answer (score 30):

You could add `visible = "legendonly"`:

```
library(plotly)
economics %>%
 transform(rate = unemploy / pop) %>%
 plot_ly(x = date, y = rate) %>%
 loess(rate ~ as.numeric(date), data = .) %>%
 broom::augment() %>%
 add_trace(y = .fitted, name = "foo", visible = "legendonly")
```

[image]

See the [reference](https://plot.ly/r/reference/).

Answer (score 7):

you can use the attribute 'visible = legendonly' to other `add_` functions such as:

```
add_lines(x = as.Date(x()$ds),
          y = round(y()$total),
          name = 'Inventory Total',
          visible = 'legendonly')
```